# domain name suggestion tool (SEO friendly)

Tags: domains, seo

I'm looking to purchase a domain, and of couse the one that I really want is taken, what would be best way to find an alternative domain that would rate good for SEO?

Answer (score 2):

- add a secondary keyword
- use a synonym
- add an "s" or other applicate suffix
- add a "the" or other applicable prefix
- use an alternate TLD (.net, .co, etc)
- use a dash if the domain consists of two words

Comment: are there any tools that checks availability and can suggest synonyms based on niche? basically some "smart" way to suggest name vs just adding "the" and/or "s"

Comment: I'm not aware of any that keep SEO in mind when making suggestions but most good registrars will offer alternatives whenever a taken domain is checked.